# How to cite articles from UNHCR in latex possibly Overleaf?

Tags: citing, natbib

I am trying to cite an article from the UNHCR.

I would like it to be in text as the following

> The United Nations High Commissioner (United Nations
>   High Commissioner for Refugees [UNHCR], 2017b).

I tried copying the bibtex from google which is the following

```
@article{united2017global,
  title={Global trends: Forced displacement in 2017},
  author={United Nations High Commissioner for Refugees},
  year={2017}
}
```

but the result was

> The United Nations High Commissioner forRefugees (2017)

even the bibliography I would like it to appear as so (not exactly this as my article is different but to give you an idea):

[image]

the article is available over here `https://www.unhcr.org/5b27be547.pdf`

The example code goes as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

The \cite{united2017global} figure shows that 30 people were forcibly displaced every minute because of conflicts or persecutions across the world in 2017.

\bibliography{Biblio.bib}
\end{document}
```

and the separate `Biblio.bib` file is as

```
@article{united2017global,
  title={Global trends: Forced displacement in 2017},
  author={{United Nations High Commissioner for Refugees}},
  url={https://www.unhcr.org/5b27be547.pdf},
  year={2017}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments I am using \usepackage{natbib} \bibliographystyle{agsm} which somehow it is mentioning  United Nations High Commissioner for Refugees (2017), ‘Global trends:  Forced displacement in 2017’

Comment: @moewe thank you for the comment just done so :)

Comment: Thanks. I retagged the question since it is not about `biblatex` (as mentioned in my last comment). Note that technically speaking `\bibliography{Biblio.bib}` is wrong. `\bibliography` takes the name of your `.bib` file *without* extension. Despite that it works with the extension on some systems. But it does not work on my system (Win 10, MikTeX 2.9). So I suggest you change to the correct `\bibliography{Biblio}`.

Comment: I guess with `author={{United Nations High Commissioner for Refugees (UNHCR)}},` you'd get close to what you want. It just doesn't switch the parenthesis style (that would be possible, but would probably require a bit of hackery).